# do some works after asynchronous function in redux saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm working on project with redux-saga.
I was using thunk before so i could do some works after api request like,

```
componentDidMount(){
  login().then((success)=>{
    redirectToProfilePage();
  })
}
```

because action in redux-thunk returns promise.
but when i'm trying to do this in redux-saga, i can't use **then** since saga doesn't return promise.

So i'm using componentWillReceiveProps to solve this, but i think it's not a appropriate solution.

Should i do this work in saga generator? Or is there any other better way?

Comment: create generator  function in your component and call that through action dispatched.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the full potential of Sagas, you will want to dispatch an action in componentDidMount.

In your sagas.js file for that component, create a function generator to listen for the action in componentDidMount:

```
function* listenForLoginAction(){
    yield takeLatest('LOGIN_ACTION', loginSaga)
}
```

Then your loginSaga will handle the async stuff in the order you tell it to. Your loginSaga could look something like this:

```
function* loginSaga(action){
    try{
        const loginResponse = yield call(loginFunc, varsForloginFunc)
        yield put({type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS', loginResponse})
    } catch (error) {
        yield put({type: 'LOGIN_FAIL', message: error.message})
    }
}
```

Using `yield call` and `yield put`, in conjuction with listening for a specific action using `takeLatest` or `takeEvery`, allows you to write code that will wait to execute until the line above it has completed.

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Thanks for help. But i think this is not what i'm asking. I want to do some works in component that dispatched action, after async stuff done.

Comment: @AnandS Sorry for late reply.. I'm trying to setState after async work finish.Or scroll to some element.